# Как записать вектор в бинарный файл?

Tags: c++, файлы

В чём разница между следующими записями? Как правильно записать вектор в бинарный файл?

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(vec.data()), vec.size() * sizeof(T));
```

или так

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(vec.data()), vec.size() * sizeof(T));
```

Comment: то есть, вопрос только в том, использовать или нет const?

Comment: @KoVadim из этих двух примеров -- да. Если есть ещё лучше вариант, то его тоже хотелось бы узнать

Comment: в данном случае абсолютно ничего не поменяется. Но вот если тип T что то сложное (например, структура или класс (к примеру std::string)) то оба способа плохи.  Как правильно? делать свой сериализатор.

Comment: @KoVadim можно преобразовывать к константному и неконстантному типу? UB не будет? `T` в данном случае `unsigned int`

Comment: Что такое `file` и `vec` в этом примере?

Comment: @user7860670 `std::ofstream`, `std::vector<unsigned int>`

Comment: Ну вот `ofstream::write` принимает `const char *`, зачем может понадобится намеренно передавать туда именно `char *`, тем самым делая невозможными запись из вектора с `const` квалификатором.

Comment: @user7860670 я тоже так подумал, но потом увидел пример https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write и ещё на стеке несколько ответов не используют const. Может быть нельзя кастить так? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast вот тут в качестве *AliasedType* указан обычный `char` без *possibly cv-qualified*

Comment: Не знаю, может быть им было просто лень добавлять `const` в каст, ведь обхект в том примере без `const` квалификатора. Но так можно делать - это 100%. Наоборот нельзя, т.е. убрать `const`, - для этого есть `const_cast`. *5) Any object pointer type T1* can be converted to another object pointer type cv T2*.*

Answer (score 0):

`ofstream::write` принимает `const char *`, зачем может понадобится намеренно передавать туда именно `char *`, тем самым делая невозможными запись из вектора с `const` квалификатором.